# CreateShortCut issue

Tags: nsis

I want to create a shortcut for a webpage which if i start it will start with the specified browser. Normaly you just have to right click on your desktop and create shortcut with this parameter :

example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" http://google.com
```

Please help me i do not no how to remake it in NSIS.

So far i have:

```
Section

CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\html\google.lnk" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe http://google.com"

SectionEnd
```

As you can see the main problem that i cannot insert more " sign in this expression

Comment: The main problem is that you did not read the documentation for CreateShortcut, it tells you how to pass a parameter to the application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A URL shortcut is not actually a .lnk, just do:

```
WriteINIStr "$SMPROGRAMS\html\google.url" "InternetShortcut" "URL" "http://google.com"
```

You can also [set a custom icon](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=251074).

If you want to force it to open in a specific browser (not a good idea) you can do:

```
CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\html\google.lnk" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "http://google.com"
```